# Navigating rspec files

Tags: navigation, code-folding, ruby-mode, breadcrumbs

Usually I use incremental searching to find what I'm looking for. Also, in general I write very small methods that easily fit in one screen. So before now I have had little use for any sort of code-folding mechanism, which is good because of [the general communal distaste for such things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399612/why-is-there-no-code-folding-in-emacs).

But one exception to this is with tests. Right now I use `rspec` and I'm finding it frustrating to navigate the tests. A test file I'm working on has about 500 lines so far and is structured like this:

```
Rspec.describe SomeClass do
  let(:some_common_variable) { create :the_thing }
  context 'with foos' do
    it 'does a thing' do
      # ... ~10 lines of arrange -> act -> assert stuff
    end
  end
  context 'with bars' do
    it 'does a thing differently' do
      # ... ~10 lines of arrange -> act -> assert stuff
    end
  end
end
```

So as you can see this makes some common-sense coding styles (like short methods) impossible.  At the end of these tests I also have:

```
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

which makes it pretty tricky to figure out which "end" I want to insert a new test after -- especially because the matching `do` is not on the screen.

**My question is:** When I'm in the middle of some test, is there some way I can generate a breadcrumb that looks like this:

```
Someclass / with foos / it does a thing
```

Right now I'm using `M-x occur` with a regex I wrote that includes things like `it`, `context`, `Rspec.describe`, etc. to get an outline. Also, **is there some code folding mode that makes it easy to quickly fold everything in an "it" block without folding everything else**, but also have the ability to fold everything else with a different command.

Answer (score 3):

This solution doesn't address code folding, but does aim to address the issue of navigation and code context awareness.

[`imenu`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Imenu.html) allows navigation of source files in all languages, including Ruby.  But `rspec` doesn't support it out of the box.  You can add support for `imenu` to rspec files with [rspec mode](https://github.com/pezra/rspec-mode) (it's in melpa).

`imenu` by itself is OK, but I highly recommend accessing it via `helm-imenu` which is built into [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm).  That will give you not only an outline of all contexts/descriptions/specs, but provide incremental substring matching to quickly jump to any of them.  Helm is available in melpa as well.

You'll no doubt continue using `occur` for more general cases, and I can again recommend using `helm-occur`, which provides the interactivity of helm when using occur to find matches.

Answer (score 1):

Use *bookmarks* to identify and return to such positions.

If you use [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then you can easily create and use [autonamed](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutonamedBookmarks) or [temporary](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#TemporaryBookmarks) (i.e., non-persistent) bookmarks, and these can be automatically [highlighted](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#HighlightingBookmarkLocations) in various ways (e.g., fringe marker or position or line), if you want.

Just hit `C-x p RET` to create an autonamed bookmark -- no need to provide a name.  A bookmark moves automatically as you update text, and an autonamed bookmark is automatically renamed to reflect the current position when you jump to it.